# Are values "ok", false, true, null, 123 valid JSON

Tags: javascript, objective-c, json

Are following strings a valid JSON?

`"ok"`

`false`

`true`

`null`

`123`

If not why do standard javascript `JSON.parse` method allow to use this values as valid JSON?

I sometimes use this values when implementing JSON REST APIs, and faced with that objective-c frameworks doesn't parse this values.

Comment: http://json.org/ they're all valid. if obj-c rejects them, then obj-c is wrong.

Comment: An example of a framework & error maybe ?

Comment: If you are just responding with string representations of primitives from your API, why use JSON at all?

Comment: @MikeBrant because JSON REST. Every request and response use `Content-Type: application/json` header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, those values by themselves are not valid JSON, which would require either an object wrapper `{}` (and configuration as key-value pair) or array wrapper `[]` around them.  There are however many JSON serialization libraries that allow for use of non-nested primitives as you have shown.  It is probably best to not rely on this behavior unless you specifically know which JSON serialization/deserialization libraries will be in use on both ends and can verify that they both support this behavior in the same manner.

Comment: I have tried Douglas Crockford's [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library. And what? All primitives parsed successfully.
By the way - Douglas Crockform is author of JSON format

Comment: @ioncreature  Again, there are a good number of libraries that understand primatives, but if you want wide compatibility, you should not rely on this.