# How to return a Boolean value from a Spring MVC controller to ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with a spring MVC controller which will return a boolean value as response to the ajax request. But when spring mvc is trying to return a boolean value it is giving me the **server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) error Please Help. Thanks in advance**

**This is my controller**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/check.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Boolean checkValue(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

**This is my Ajax method**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            url : 'check.html',
            success : function(response) {
                if(response===true)
                {
                    window.alert("true");
                }
                else
                {
                    window.alert("false");
                }
            },
            error : function(e){
                window.alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing same problem when I was returning a string to the AJAX request. But I solved it using HttpServletResponse object. You can also do it like this way.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/check.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void checkValue(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse){

    /*Your Logic*/
    httpServletResponse.getWriter().println(true);
    httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();

}
```

Now you can get a boolean response and you can use **response** in your javascript code as a boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think some primitive values may not be [valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871442/are-values-ok-false-true-null-123-valid-json). I would normally return a map looking like `{"status": true}` in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `produces` attribute to your `@RequestMapping` so

```
@RequestMapping(value="/check.html",method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json" )
```

To understand your problem read about the [content negotiation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) in spring.

The extension of your request `check.html` is considered when the frameworks reasons about the return type, and it gives a hint that the response should be `html`. The annotation `@ResponseBody` tries to add a content to response's body.

When you return a primitive `true` the framework attempts to find a converter that will convert the `true` value to `HTML`. It fails, and you get your error message.

With the produces set to `application/json`, it will use the underlying converter (jackson if you didn't change the defaults),  and it will convert without issues